# aws lambda invoke to put multiple files from one bucket to other?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Can some one help me how to put multiple files from a s3 folder to another using aws cli lambda invoke.

**Updated question**

Requirement:

1. Multiple files loaded in source bucket/folder.These files retention is 1 day.
2. So I need to copy to the archive folder in another bucket..
3. Target folder structure bucket/folder/yyy-mm-dd/

Existing process: s3 event created in source bucket with prefix enabled for specific folder. Lambda code (pasted below doing the work).

Issues: If I have to invoke some day manually lambda function, how to pass the key. As the keys are multiple files.

**Existing code for single file:**

```
aws lambda invoke  --function-name abcdeffe_job  --payload '{"Records":[{"eventTime": "2020-03-07T23:38:16.762Z","s3":{"bucket": {"name": "xxxx-test"},"object": {"key": "lambda-test/account.csv"}}}]}' abc.txt
```

I have got mulitple account file such as account_1.csv, account_2.csv **** so on.
How can I pass the key here?

Lambda code:

```
import json
import boto3
import urllib.parse
import time

s3_client =boto3.client('s3')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    file_event_time = event['Records'][0]['eventTime']
    print("file_event_time :",file_event_time)
    ts = time.strptime(file_event_time[:19], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
    dt=time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d", ts)
    # Bucket Name where file was uploaded
    source_bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    print("source_bucket_name : ",source_bucket_name)
    # Bucket Name where file to be uploaded
    destination_bucket_name = 'test'
    # Filename of object (with path)
    #file_key_name  = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'],encoding='utf-8')
    file_key_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    print("file_key_name : ",file_key_name)
    file_name=file_key_name.split("/")[1]
    print("file_name : ",file_name)
    # Copy Source Object
    copy_source_object = {'Bucket': source_bucket_name, 'Key': file_key_name}
    print(" The target folder to be created for :",dt)
    destination_file_path ="art_jobs"+"/"+dt+"/"+file_name
    print("destination_file_path : ",destination_file_path)
    try:
        response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=source_bucket_name, Key=file_key_name)
        print("response :",response)
        s3_client.copy_object(CopySource=copy_source_object, Bucket=destination_bucket_name, Key=destination_file_path)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise e
```

Comment: You may want to consider having the Lambda function handle multiple files, more efficient. If this is a "sync" type of a job, S3 can trigger Lambda on object upload, which then copies the file to your target bucket. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-configure-s3-event-notification/

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. Could you please edit your Question and add more details? For example, what should "trigger" this process (eg file creation, or is something invoking the Lambda function)? How are the "files to be copied" identified -- are they passed to the Lambda function? Is the destination always the same? What is the `abc.txt` at the end of your sample `invoke` command? Basically, please describe the end-to-end process you would like to implement.

Comment: Have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

## To iterate over objects

```
 for My_Bucket_Object in Target_Bucket.objects.all():                
     Lambda_Client.invoke(FunctionName="Fn-Name",InvocationType='Event',Payload=json.dumps(Sample_Event))
```

## To copy the object

```
    s3_resource = boto3.resource("s3")

    sourceLoc = "Bucket-Name-source/Key.csv"

    s3_resource.Object("Bucket-Namedestination","Key.csv").copy_from(CopySource = sourceLoc)
```

## To delete the object

```
    response = s3_client.delete_object(
        Bucket='Bucket-Name-source',
        Key="Key.csv"
    )
```